# Angular2 Oninit() how to specify data-bound properties to watch for?

Tags: angular

For example, I have two input properties:

```
@Input() field1;
@Input() field2;
```

Every time I initialize field1, I want function1() to be called; every time I initialzie field2, I want function2() to be called. I guess this is similar to OnInit, but not quite. Is there any ways to solve the issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first time input properties are bound (and every subsequent time thereafeter), the `ngOnChanges` hook is invoked per the [lifecycle documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#onchanges).

You can can bind each property to a `SimpleChange` object that exposes new and previous state:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: {[propertyName: string]: SimpleChange}) {
  for (let propName in changes) {
    if (propName === 'field1')
      this.function1();

    if (propName === 'field2')
      this.function2();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends on

- what you mean by "initialize", and
- what the types for the two input properties are

If "initialize" always means assigning a new value, then see @DavidL's answer.  
Note that if the input property types are JavaScript reference types (Array, Object, etc.), then "assigning a new value" means assigning a new Array, Object, etc.  It does not include modifying an Array item or an Object property.  Read on for that scenario...

If the input property types are JavaScript reference types, and "initialize" could mean changing an Array item's value or changing an Object property's value, then `ngOnChanges` can't be used, since the reference does not change in this scenario, hence Angular change detection does not see this as a change.  For this scenario, implement [ngDoCheck](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#docheck) and write your own change detection logic inside that method.

Comment: You should answer more often Mark. There's a huge lack of good answers on angular2.

Comment: @EricMartinez, I have this thing called a job that keeps getting in the way.  (I'm not complaining, I like my job.)

Comment: Oh man, jobs are evil, they even make you think you like them! I hope to see you more often over here!